# function returning vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, unsigned-integer

I have a function returning a vector in MatLab, the problem is that function should return a unsigned integer value, I've debugged my code and I realize that the variable `galois_value` turns into a vector when I do a `bitand` and a `bitxor` operation. I've tried to do a `typecast` to turn the vector into a unsigned value but doesn't works. I've tried to force a cast, but doesn't works too. Below the function:

```
function galois_value = galois_mul2( value )
    hex = uint8(hex2dec('1B')); 
    temp = typecast(value, 'int8');
    temp = bitshift(temp,-7); 
    temp = bitand(typecast(temp,'uint8'),hex); 
    galois_value =  bitxor(bitshift(value,1),uint16(temp)); 
end
```

The correct output of this function should be (this output comes from a C code that is working) :

```
96
210
97
224
119
194
192
156
196
195
102
10
10
117
235
213
49
57
235
79
172
5
23
62
111
188
223
128
113
133
128
102
30
238
226
31
```

The output I get with the MatLab function:

```
96     96

210    210

353    378

224    224

375    364

194    194

192    192

156    156

196    196

451    472

102    102

 10     10

 10     10

373    366

491    496

469    462

305    298

313    290

491    496

335    340

172    172

261    286

279    268

 62     62

367    372

188    188

479    452

128    128

369    362

389    414

128    128

102    102

 30     30

238    238

226    226

287    260
```

The code to display and debug the function:

```
%Key
key = {'00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','0a','0b','0c','0d','0e','0f'};
for n = 1 : 16
   keyU(n)=uint16(hex2dec(key(n)));
end
%State
state = {'00','11','22','33','44','55','66','77','88','99','aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff'};
for n = 1 : 16
   stateU(n)=uint16(hex2dec(state(n)));
end
%Sbox
sbox = {'63','7c','77','7b','f2','6b','6f','c5','30','01','67','2b','fe','d7','ab','76','ca','82','c9','7d','fa','59','47','f0','ad','d4','a2','af','9c','a4','72','c0','b7','fd','93','26','36','3f','f7','cc','34','a5','e5','f1','71','d8','31','15','04','c7','23','c3','18','96','05','9a','07','12','80','e2','eb','27','b2','75','09','83','2c','1a','1b','6e','5a','a0','52','3b','d6','b3','29','e3','2f','84','53','d1','00','ed','20','fc','b1','5b','6a','cb','be','39','4a','4c','58','cf','d0','ef','aa','fb','43','4d','33','85','45','f9','02','7f','50','3c','9f','a8','51','a3','40','8f','92','9d','38','f5','bc','b6','da','21','10','ff','f3','d2','cd','0c','13','ec','5f','97','44','17','c4','a7','7e','3d','64','5d','19','73','60','81','4f','dc','22','2a','90','88','46','ee','b8','14','de','5e','0b','db','e0','32','3a','0a','49','06','24','5c','c2','d3','ac','62','91','95','e4','79','e7','c8','37','6d','8d','d5','4e','a9','6c','56','f4','ea','65','7a','ae','08','ba','78','25','2e','1c','a6','b4','c6','e8','dd','74','1f','4b','bd','8b','8a','70','3e','b5','66','48','03','f6','0e','61','35','57','b9','86','c1','1d','9e','e1','f8','98','11','69','d9','8e','94','9b','1e','87','e9','ce','55','28','df','8c','a1','89','0d','bf','e6','42','68','41','99','2d','0f','b0','54','bb','16'}; 
for n = 1 : 256
   sboxU(n)=uint16(hex2dec(sbox(n)));
end
%Rcon
rcon = {'01','02','04','08','10','20','40','80','1b','36'};
for n = 1 : 10
   rconU(n)=uint16(hex2dec(rcon(n)));
end
%Main AES Data Loop
for round = 1 : 10
%Add key + sbox 
    for i = 1 : 16
        stateU(i)= sboxU(bitxor(stateU(i),keyU(i))+1);
    end
%Shift Rows
    buf1 = stateU(2);
    stateU(2) = stateU(6);
    stateU(6) = stateU(10);
    stateU(10) = stateU(14);
    stateU(14) = buf1;

    buf1 = stateU(3);
    buf2 = stateU(7);
    stateU(3) = stateU(11);
    stateU(7) = stateU(15);
    stateU(11) = buf1;
    stateU(15) = buf2;

    buf1 = stateU(16);
    stateU(16) = stateU(12);
    stateU(12) = stateU(8);
    stateU(8) = stateU(4);
    stateU(4) = buf1;
%Process mixcolumn for all rounds but the last one
    if round < 10
        for j = 0 : 3
%Compute the current index
            buf4 = (bitshift(j,2));
            %buf1
            aux1 = bitxor(stateU(buf4+1),stateU(buf4+2));
            aux2 = bitxor(stateU(buf4+3),stateU(buf4+4));
            buf1 = bitxor(aux1,aux2);
            %buf2
            buf2 = stateU(buf4+1);
            %buf3
            buf3 = bitxor(stateU(buf4+1),stateU(buf4+2));
           buf3 = galois_mul2(buf3);
            disp(buf3);
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line 3 of galois_mul2 function
temp = typecast(value, 'int8');
since value has type uint16 output of typecast is two elements.
for e.g. output of typecast(uint16(5), 'int8') is 5 0
If you change all types in lines 3,8,13,18 of main and lines 3,6 of galois_mul2 function to uint8 the problem will be solved.